# Creating a new row in empty datatable and get correct next OID

Tags: c#, datatable, datarow, oid, objectid

I know this seems really simple but doesn't seem to work. I have a table in MsAccess database that is empty but it did have some records at some point, when i do DataTable.NewRow it returns a new row where objectid field is 0 (autoincerement field). after i commit this new row to database it has objectid 84 (or whaterver it think next number should be) but i need to have correct objectid value before commit because its used in a join table. if i have at least 1 record on my datatable and do datatable.NewRow, then objectid for new row will be correct 84. Here is code i'm using to get datatable:

```
                string sSQL = "Select * from <tableName>"                   
                IDbDataAdapter dbAdapter = GetDataAdapter(sSQL);
                dbAdapter.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey;
                if (DbConnection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    DbConnection.Open();
                try
                {
                    DataAdapterFill(dbAdapter, dataSet, sTableName);
                }
                catch (OleDbException oledbEx)
                {
                    if (oledbEx.Message.Contains("No value given for one or more required parameters"))
                        throw new Exception(string.Format("Where clause {0} contains correct fields for table {1}", sWhereClause, sTableName), oledbEx);
                    else
                        throw oledbEx;
                }
                catch
                {
                    DbConnection.Close();
                    ((IDisposable)dbAdapter).Dispose();
                    throw;
                }
                dbAdapter.TableMappings.Add(sTableName, sTableName);
                dataTable = dataSet.Tables[0];
```

Comment: `@@Identity` look at this link it should be what you are looking for 
[HOW TO Retrieve the Identity Value While Inserting Records into Access Database By Using Visual Basic .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815629)